# Cant seem to get mining started

Tags: mining, full-node

I'm using the Low Graphics Mode GUI

- Daemon is synchronized
- Network status = Connected
- Wallet blocks remaining: 456

Under Solo Mining I click on 'Use recommended number of threads' which sets it to 2 out of max 4.

Then I click Start Mining.. I get "Error starting mining Couldn't start mining."

I click OK. Now Network status = Connecting.

I can see in Task Manager that 'monerod.exe' is running and using resources, mainly Disk and Memory

After a short while I'm back to Daemon is synchronized..
but I cant seem to get mining started.

Network status keeps changing between Connecting and Connected.

Any ideas what might be wrong?

Comment: This has just appeared in the log: [03/12/2021 15:53] 2021-12-03 15:44:46.505 I Monero 'Oxygen Orion' (v0.17.2.3-release) 
Error: Problem fetching info-- rpc_request: 
Height: 2462476/2506847 (98.2%) on mainnet, mining info unavailable, net hash 2.63 GH/s, v14, 12(out)+14(in) connections, uptime 0d 0h 13m 49s

Comment: "2462476/2506847 (98.2%)" you are not fully synchronized.